# jQuery Validation Form Plugin on jQuery loaded form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I posted about this earlier and I was very excited about the possibility of jQuery validation plugin being a solution. Perhaps I'm just missing something...

What I want to do is use jQuery `.load()` to load a form into a div and then use the jQuery validation plugin to validate the page. My page works 100% with the jQuery `.load()`, so everything except the jQuery form validation is working. I got the validation plugin working great on a normal static page, but once I try to implement it on my existing site using `.load()` it stops functioning as expected.

Instead of jQuery alerting the user about invalid fields on submit, the page reloads and takes them back to the main page. What am I doing wrong?

Script to load pages into content div located in head of index file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $formLoad = false;
    $('div#happenings').load('happenings.html #happenings_content'); 
    $('div#menu_content').load('home.html #contentA');
    $('div#page_content').load('home.html #contentB');
    $("div#menu ul li a").click(function() {
        var ifContact = $(this).attr('href'); 
            $('div#menu ul li a').removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
        $(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active"); 
        $('div#menu_content').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #contentA');
        $('div#page_content').load(($(this).attr('href') + '#contentB'), 
            function(){ 
                if (ifContact == 'contact.html') { extra bit goes here }); 
            }
                }
        ); <!--FINISH LOADING PAGE CONTENT-->
        return false;
    }); 
});
</script>
```

jQuery validation script located in head of index file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($,W,D) {
var JQUERY4U = {};

JQUERY4U.UTIL =
{
    setupFormValidation: function()
    {
        //form validation rules
        $("#register-form").validate({
            rules: {
                fullname: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },      
            },
            messages: {
                fullname: "Please enter your firstname",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    }
}

//when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
$(D).ready(function($) {
    JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
});
})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

and the form which is loaded from a div in contact.html:

```
<div id="mailform">
<form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div id="form-content">
    <div class="fieldgroup">
        <label for="fullname">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname">
    </div>


    <div class="fieldgroup">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">
    </div>

    <div class="fieldgroup">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <div class="fieldgroup">
        <label for="comment" class="commenttop">Comment:</label>
        <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="60" rows="10"       
                      maxlength="1000"></textarea>
    </div>  

    <div class="fieldgroup">        
        <input type="checkbox" name="mailinglist" value="Please sign me up 
                       for your mailing list!" checked="yes" />
        <label for="mailinglist">Please sign me up for your mailing list!   
                       </label>
    </div>

    <div class="fieldgroup">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="submit"> 
    </div>

    </div>
</form>

</div> <!-- END MAILFORM-->
```

Comment: `.validate()` is the _initialization_ for the plugin and the form must be loaded before you run `.validate()`.  So simply run `.validate()` immediately after you load the form's HTML into the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the live() function.

```
    setupFormValidation: function()    
        {
        $('.submit').live('click', function() {

            //form validation rules    
            $("#register-form").validate({

                rules: {
                    fullname: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },      
                },
                messages: {
                    fullname: "Please enter your firstname",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                },

                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
       )};
 }
```

Comment: You absolutely do not want to _intialize_ jQuery Validate on the `submit` event.  `.validate()` (initialization) should be done _after_ the form is created but _before_ the button is clicked.